# bankID as a key for storing purpose for Select option in Drupal form API

Tags: forms

I've created a drupal custom form. I've used a select option for bank which get its value from the bank table. I want to store bankID in bankbranch table and which is a foreign key and display bank name in select box but it shows me an error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$bankID in bankbranch_form() (line 40 of
>   C:\wamp\www\emp\sites\all\modules\bankbranch\bankbranch.module).

```
/**
* Implements hook_permission().
*/
function bankbranch_permission() {
  return array(
    'submit bankbranch' => array(
      'title' => t('submit bank branch'),
      'description' => t('submit bank branch form'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function bankbranch_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['bankbranch'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bank Branch Entry Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit bankbranch'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('bankbranch_form'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
* Bank Branch Form
*/
function bankbranch_form($form, &$form_state){
  $query_bank = db_select('bank', 's')
    -> fields('s', array('bankID', 'bankname'))
    -> execute()
    -> fetchAll();
  $options_bank = array();
  foreach($query_bank as $value) {
    //bankID as key 
    $options_bank[$value->bankID] = t($value->bankname); /** line for which it shows notice*/
  }
  $form['bankID'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select Bank Name'),
    '#options' => $options_bank,
    '#size' => 1,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchName'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Name'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchaddress'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Address'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['branchcode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch Code'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['ifsccode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Branch IFSC code'),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add item'),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
* Submit handler for the bank_form. Insert entry into the database.
*/
function bankbranch_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $branchID = db_insert('bankbranch')
    ->fields(array(
      'bankID' => $form_state['values']['bankID'],
      'brachName' => $form_state['values']['brachName'],
      'branchaddress' => $form_state['values']['branchaddress'],
      'branchcode' => $form_state['values']['branchcode'],
      'ifsccode' => $form_state['values']['ifsccode'],   
    ))
    ->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('Your form entry has been added'));
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In submit handler `print_r($form_state['values']) ` and check bank id is getting or not.